# Не корректное сохранение файла

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, файлы

Вот код метода который сохраняет в файл данные с `EditView`:

```
final private File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder");
private void saveFile(String fileName) {
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        File file = new File(folder, fileName);
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferWriter.write(mEditText.getText().toString());
            bufferWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("myLogs", t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

На `API` 21+ работает нормально. На `API` 19 и ниже выдает вот такую ошибку при вызове данного метода:

```
08-25 10:11:38.372  24688-24688/com.marazmone.testfilesystem D/myLogs﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyFolder/Tue Aug 25 10:03:51 GMT 2015: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

**Обновление**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Фишка в том что на `lollipop` работает на `kitkat` пишет ошибку

Comment: В манифесте пермишны прописаны?

Comment: Файл который приходит с именем fileName надо тоже по аналогии с папкой создать через mkdir()